# Doctrine error select in select subquery

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

That's my problem:
I'm trying to make a sub select inside a select with doctrine but already told me that i have bounded too few parameters. 
That's my code:

```
 //eseguo un group by per capire quali diciture mostrare nel select
            $repoMappatura = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CombinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli');
            $qb = $repoMappatura->createQueryBuilder('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli')
                ->leftJoin('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.albero', 'albero')
                ->select('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.valore')
                ->where('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.albero = :albe')
                ->setParameter('albe', $alberoFiglio);
            $count = 894;
            /** @var  $vincolo VincoliControlloAlberiFigliConfiguratore[]*/
            foreach ($alberoFiglio->getVincoli() as $vincolo)
            {
                if (key_exists($vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId(), $arrayChiaviVincoli)) {
                    $log->info('Esistente in array! Valore: ' . $arrayChiaviVincoli[$vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId()]);
                    $qb2 = $repoMappatura->createQueryBuilder('qb2Mappa');
                    $qb = $qb->andWhere(
                        $qb->expr()->in('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.id',
                            $qb2->select('qb2Mappa.id')
                                ->where('qb2Mappa.valore = :val' . $count)
                                ->andWhere('qb2Mappa.albero = :alb')
                                ->setParameters(['val' . $count => $arrayChiaviVincoli[$vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId()], 'alb' . $count => $alberoFiglio])
                            ->getDQL()
                        )
                    );
                    $count++;
                }
            }
            $qb = $qb->groupBy('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.valore')
                ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

That is the returned error by symfony:

> Too few parameters: the query defines 3 parameters but you only bound 1

I have also tried to use the

> ->setParameters(....)

to $qb and not to $qb2 but the result is the same

> Too few parameters: the query defines 3 parameters but you only bound 2

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with this code:

```
$repoMappatura = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CombinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli');
            $qb = $repoMappatura->createQueryBuilder('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli')
                ->leftJoin('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.albero', 'albero')
                ->leftJoin('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.mappaCategorieArticoli', 'mappaCategorieArticoli')
                ->select('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.valore')
                ->where('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.albero = ?1')
                ->setParameter(1, $alberoFiglio);
            $count = 2;
            /** @var  $vincolo VincoliControlloAlberiFigliConfiguratore*/
            foreach ($alberoFiglio->getVincoli() as $vincolo)
            {
                if (key_exists($vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId(), $arrayChiaviVincoli)) {
                    $log->info('Esistente in array! Valore: ' . $arrayChiaviVincoli[$vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId()]);
                    $qb2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CombinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli')->createQueryBuilder('qb2Mappa'.$count)
                        ->leftJoin('qb2Mappa'.$count.'.albero', 'alber'.$count)
                        ->leftJoin('qb2Mappa'.$count.'.mappaCategorieArticoli', 'mpc'.$count)
                        ->select('mpc'.$count.'.id')
                        ->where('qb2Mappa'.$count.'.valore = ?' . $count)
                        ->andWhere('alber'.$count.'.id = ?' . ($count + 1));

                    $qb = $qb->andWhere(
                        $qb->expr()->in('mappaCategorieArticoli.id',$qb2->getDQL())
                    )->setParameter($count, $arrayChiaviVincoli[$vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId()])
                        ->setParameter($count + 1, $vincolo->getAlberoVincolo()->getId());
                }
                $count = $count + 2;
            }
            $log->info($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());
            $log->info(count($qb->getParameters()));
            $qb = $qb->groupBy('combinazioneAlberoMappaCategorieArticoli.valore')
                ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Added count parameter to make each for loop different and add manually parameters with ? . $count